# Plot for Function not looping

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot h vs. eig_gs but it only returns one value. First of all Hamiltonian is defined as follows:

```
def Hamiltonian(alpha,h):

    Sx = np.array([[0,1],[1,0]])
    Sy = np.array([[0,-1j],[1j,0]])
    Sz = np.array([[1,0],[0,-1]])
    I  = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])

    H = ( (alpha*np.kron(np.kron(Sx,Sx),I))
       + (alpha*np.kron(np.kron(Sy,Sy),I))
       + (alpha*np.kron(np.kron(I,Sx),Sx))
       + (alpha*np.kron(np.kron(I,Sy),Sy))
       + (h*np.kron(np.kron(I,Sz),I)) )

    return H
```

Which returns an 8x8 matrix I can use for my work. My question is what is wrong in my code to stop it from looping over all oh h rather than just the last value? I have tried sticking H inside the for loop but this does not change the value and i have tried writing is as

```
H = Hamiltonian(1,h.size)
```

(inside the for loop) But this does not solve the problem

```
# Computation of eigenvalues from density matrix

h = np.array([0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0])
eig_gs = np.zeros(h.size, dtype = 'complex')

for i in range(h.size):
    H = Hamiltonian(1,h.size)
    eigvals, eigvecs = LA.eigh(H)

    # Density of the GS
    g_state = eigvecs[:,0]
    rho_gs = np.outer(g_state, g_state.conjugate())

    # Expectation value of the energy GS density matrix
    eig_gs[i] = np.trace(rho_gs.dot(H))

plt.plot(h, eig_gs.real)
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

If I put the plt.plot in the for loop I get the following (which doesn't make sense):

[image]

Comment: I think you forgot to tell what `Hamiltonian` is. In general make sure the code is runnable by itself.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest AHH yes I have forgotten thank you I'll edit it now

Comment: You haven't put your plot command in the for loop. Isn't that the reason why you are just getting one value?

Comment: Your `eig_gs` has length 11 and all are same values. Your energy values are 11-fold degenerate

Comment: @Bazingaa I changed the question to reflect your first comment thanks for the input. How do I ensure I get different eig_gs values though? When I print them for different hamiltonians I get different answers but when I try to plot them it only returns the one degenerate value

Comment: You are not changing the Hamiltonian, so of course for a given Hamiltonian, you will have a corresponding set of eigenvalues. For the Hamiltonian you defined, you have 11-fold degenerate eigenvalues. To get different eigenvalues, you need a different Hamiltonian, right?

Comment: Ahh yes but how do I change the Hamiltonian inside the for loop to reflect that? I'm trying to do it so it gives a H, then eigenvalue to work with for each iteration and then plot all the iterations at the end. But when I have something like H(1,h.size) it doesn't achieve this

Comment: What is the use of `h` in your code? I don't see it. You are just looping over the length of h and the Hamiltonian is the same everytime. You need to see for yourself,, what your Hamiltonian should look like. How does your Hamiltonian depends on `h`?

Comment: I created the array to populate H with those values

Comment: I feel like it's a very simple mistake I'm making with the Hamiltonian and the loop all I need is for it to create a new Hamiltonian for each iteration of i so the eigenvalues change

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Check my answer and let me know if it's what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put Hamiltonian inside the for loop and pass the corresponding `h` value while computing Hamiltonian. After appending all the eigenvalues, you can plot them outside the for loop. The result below shows the discrete energy spectrum obtained by solving your eigenvalue problem. The discrete energy levels can be visualized best using horizontal lines plotted using `axhline`

```
for i in range(h.size):
    H = Hamiltonian(1,h[i]) # Update the Hamiltonian
    eigvals, eigvecs = LA.eigh(H)
    # Density of the GS
    g_state = eigvecs[:,0]
    rho_gs = np.outer(g_state, g_state.conjugate())
    # Expectation value of the energy GS density matrix
    eig_gs[i] = np.trace(rho_gs.dot(H))

for i in range(h.size):
    plt.axhline(eig_gs[i].real)
```

[image]

Comment: h[i]!!! I knew it was very simple thank you very much Bazingaa you legend

Comment: I have done these similar problems involving solving Schrödinger equation myself so I knew where the problem was ;)